# Magento checkout page redirect to cart after filling information with checkout as guest user

Tags: magento

Magento checkout page redirect to cart after filling information with checkout as guest user only but working fine when user logged in or register

In console i am getting this error:

GET https://www.femmenova.com/en/checkout/onepage/progress/?toStep=shipping_method

500 Internal Server Error
        2.57s

Comment: Check `var/log` for more details or the server log file.

Answer (score 0):

Ashutosh,Please check coding on Onepagecontroller.php progressAction,also check coding on progress.phtml at  template\checkout\onepage.

Comment: thanx amit for your reply!!! my problem is solved now, i have replaced  some code part in the progressAction .....Thanx again

Comment: Yes but what was the issue actually in there ? I am encountering the same issue now and due to no help available online I cannot solve it. Moreover neither logging is working nor any errors displayed in the Browser console. So you must let me know what was the issue and how did you fixed it ?